# 1010! game implementation with bruteforce AI

Tags: c++, performance, c++14

I made a program which is supposed to be an implementation of the game [1010!](http://1010ga.me/) with support for custom AI agents, minus some pieces available in the original game.

It works great for the 1 agent that I made, but it is not really fast IMO. I know that bruteforce is in itself slow, but I still have a feeling that my game implementation isn't fast enough, or rather, I want to know if I wrote it as efficient as possible.

Here is some data, measured with the `time` command and compiled using `-03`:

```
| n. of iterations | real time |
|------------------------------|
| 1'000            | 0.047s    |
| 1'000'000        | 17.035s   |
| 2'000'000        | 35.423s   |
```

My program has only 1 class, `game` which is the actual implementation of the game, without any AI stuff. The AI agents are implemented using a function with the signature `void(game&)`. I wrote a helper function `start_agent` to streamline the testing environment.

So here is the code (I inlined some headers to make the code easier to read here).

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "game.h"

namespace tenten {

    void bruteforce_run(game& board) noexcept {
        while (true) {
            bool foundLocation = false;

            for (auto i = 0u; i < game::current_pieces_num; ++i) {
                bool nextPiece = false;
                for (auto x = 0u; x < game::columns && !nextPiece; ++x) {
                    for (auto y = 0u; y < game::rows && !nextPiece; ++y) {
                        if (board.try_add_piece(i, x, y)) {
                            foundLocation = true;
                            nextPiece = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!foundLocation)
                break;
        }
    }

}


template<typename Func>
void start_agent(Func&& agent_func, std::string name, int iterations) {
    std::cout << "Starting " << name << " agent...\n";
    tenten::game game;
    std::cout << "Running...\n";

    auto highscore = 0ul;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
        agent_func(game);
        if (game.get_score() > highscore)
            highscore = game.get_score();;
        game.reset();
    }

    std::cout << "Highscore of " << name << ": " << highscore << '\n';
}

inline void nice_seperator() { std::cout << "=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n"; }

int main() {
    std::cout << "Booting up...\n";
    std::cout << "Starting 1010!\n";
    std::cout << "And go!\n";
    nice_seperator();
    start_agent(tenten::bruteforce_run, "bruteforce", 1'000'000);
}
```

game.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>



namespace tenten {

class game {
    using uint128_t = boost::multiprecision::uint128_t; // boost has long namespace names :(
public:
    static constexpr unsigned int rows = 10;
    static constexpr unsigned int columns = 10;
    static constexpr int current_pieces_num = 3;
    static constexpr int pieces_num = 4;

    game() noexcept;
    void display() const noexcept;
    void reset() noexcept;

    bool try_add(uint128_t piece, unsigned int x, unsigned int y) noexcept;
    bool try_add_piece(unsigned int piece_index, unsigned int x, unsigned int y) noexcept;

    inline auto get_current_pieces() const noexcept { return current_pieces; }
    inline std::size_t get_pieces_size() const noexcept { return current_pieces_num; }
    inline auto get_score() const noexcept { return score; }

private:
    uint128_t board;
    uint128_t current_pieces[current_pieces_num];
    const uint128_t pieces[pieces_num] = {
        0,                                           // empty piece
        1,                                           // 1x1 square 
        (3 << columns) | 3,                          // 2x2 square
        (7 << columns * 2) | (7 << columns) | 7,     // 3x3 square
    };
    unsigned long score = 0;

    void remove_piece(unsigned int index) noexcept;
    void regen_pieces() noexcept;
    void calculate_score() noexcept;
};

}
```

game.cpp

```
#include "game.h"


#include <random>
#include <vector>


namespace tenten {

constexpr unsigned int game::rows;
constexpr unsigned int game::columns;
constexpr int game::current_pieces_num;
constexpr int game::pieces_num;

game::game() noexcept {
    regen_pieces();
}



bool game::try_add(uint128_t piece, unsigned int x, unsigned int y) noexcept {
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= columns || y >= rows || piece == 0)
        return false;

    auto pieceAtPos = (piece << x) << (y * rows);

    // Conflict-with-another-tile detection
    if (((board ^ pieceAtPos) & pieceAtPos) != pieceAtPos)
        return false;

    // Check for horizontal out of bounds access
    uint128_t currentRow = 0;
    uint128_t width = 0;
    while ((currentRow = (piece >> (currentRow * columns).convert_to<unsigned long long>()) & ((1u << columns) - 1)) != 0) {
        auto mostSigniBit = 1;
        while ((currentRow >> mostSigniBit) != 0)
            ++mostSigniBit;
        if (mostSigniBit > width)
            width = mostSigniBit;
    }

    if (x + width - 1 >= columns)
        return false;

    // If unused bits are set then piece is too long
    auto unusedBits = ~uint128_t(0) << (rows * columns);
    if (((board | pieceAtPos) & unusedBits) != 0)
        return false;


    // Modified SO algorithm http://stackoverflow.com/a/109915/3980929
    int count = 0;
    {
        auto copy = piece;
        while (copy != 0) {
            if ((copy & 1) == 1)
                ++count;
            copy >>= 1;
      }
    }

    score += count;
    board ^= pieceAtPos;
    calculate_score();

    return true;
}



void game::display() const noexcept {
    for (auto i = 0u; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (auto j = 0u; j < columns; ++j) {
            auto bit = uint128_t(1) << (j + i * rows);
            std::cout << ((board & bit) == bit) << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << "===========================\n";
}



bool game::try_add_piece(unsigned int pieceIndex, unsigned int x, unsigned int y) noexcept {
    if (current_pieces[pieceIndex] == pieces[0])
        return false;

    bool result = false;
    if ((result = try_add(current_pieces[pieceIndex], x, y)))
        remove_piece(pieceIndex);
    return result;
}



void game::remove_piece(unsigned int index) noexcept {
    current_pieces[index] = pieces[0];

    bool remainingPieces = false;
    for (auto piece : current_pieces) {
        if (piece != pieces[0]) {
            remainingPieces = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!remainingPieces)
        regen_pieces();
}



void game::regen_pieces() noexcept {
    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::mt19937 mt{ rd() };
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uid(1, pieces_num);

    for (auto& piece : current_pieces)
        piece = pieces[uid(mt)];
}



void game::calculate_score() noexcept {
    static_assert(rows == columns, "Fix calculate_score if you want to have a rectangle board!");

    std::vector<char> rows_to_delete;
    std::vector<char> columns_to_delete;

    // Check one row and one column at the time
    for (auto num = 0u; num < rows; ++num) {
        // Check for finished rows
        uint128_t row = (board >> (num * columns)) & ((1u << columns) - 1);

        // Check for finished columns
        bool finished = true;
        for (auto row = 0u; row < rows; ++row) {
            if (((board >> (row * columns)) & (1u << num)) != (1u << num)) {
                finished = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (row == ((1u << columns) - 1))
            rows_to_delete.push_back(num);
        if (finished)
            columns_to_delete.push_back(num);
    }

    for (auto row : rows_to_delete) {
        board &= ~((((uint128_t(1) << (columns * (row + 1))) - 1) >> (columns * row)) << (columns * row));
        score += 10;
    }
    for (auto column : columns_to_delete) {
        uint128_t column_num = 1u << column;
        for (auto row = 0u; row < rows - 1; ++row) {
            column_num <<= columns;
            column_num |= 1u << column;
        }
        board &= ~column_num;
        score += 10;
    }

}



void game::reset() noexcept {
    board = 0;
    score = 0;
    regen_pieces();
}

}
```

Also, if you have general suggestions, please post them, I'll be happy to learn something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Complicated check

This check looks pretty complicated:

> ```
>  if (((board ^ pieceAtPos) & pieceAtPos) != pieceAtPos)
>       return false;
> ```

Let's find out what it is doing:

```
board   pieceAtPos   result
-----   ----------   ------
  0         0           0
  0         1           0
  1         0           0
  1         1           1
```

So in other words, a simple bitwise and.  So you could rewrite that as:

```
if (board & pieceAtPos)
    return false;
```

#### Detecting horizontal out of bounds

Currently you use a double loop to check for a piece being out of bounds horizontally.  You can make this check very simple by creating an array of shapes that are walls of varying thicknesses.  Suppose you create an array of pieces `vwall`, where `vwall[n]` is a piece that consists of an `n` wide vertical wall touching the left edge.  Then, to check if `piece` at position `x` is out of bounds, you just do:

```
if (piece & vwall[x])
    return false;
```

Or you could precompute the width of each piece, and pass in the piece number into your function.  Then the check would be:

```
if (widthOfPiece[pieceNum] + x > columns)
    return false;
```

#### Counting bits

You use a loop to count the number of bits in a piece.  This is very time consuming.  I would suggest precomputing the number of bits in each piece, and passing in the piece number into your function.  That way you could just do:

```
score += scoreForPiece[pieceNum];
```

#### Checking for completed rows/cols

Similarly, the check you have for completed rows and columns would be much easier if you precomputed pieces which represented full rows and colums.  Then your code would look something like this:

```
void game::calculate_score() noexcept {
    uint128_t newBoard = board;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        if (board & fullRow[i] == fullRow[i]) {
            score += 10;
            newBoard &= ~fullRow[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        if (board & fullCol[i] == fullCol[i]) {
            score += 10;
            newBoard &= ~fullCol[i];
        }
    }
    board = newBoard;
}
```

Comment: Wow! It only takes 4.145s for 2'000'000 iterations! Thanks! :)